# Floating spheres canvas

Tags: html, css, canvas, css-transitions

I'm very curious to how the effect on the bottom of branch's website is achieved (http://branch.com/)? The red spheres connected with lines? Where would be the right place to start learning something like this

Comment: http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use chrome browser, then via console you can trace this js file and you can learn how the red spheres are achieved.

http://static.branch.com/assets/home/signed_out_splash.m-a8d55753205b7abc8302ac3019633789.js

To learn you can refer
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Canvas
http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/2dcontext/html5_canvas/